# How to get form validation groups defined as closure function which were used by handleRequest method?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Based on example presented in doc

```php
$resolver->setDefaults([
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            if (Client::TYPE_PERSON == $data->getType()) {
                return ['person'];
            }            
            return ['company'];
        },
    ]);
```

In my controller I would like to get an array of groups which were used by `$form->handleRequest($request);`

I can get the closure by `$form->getConfig()->getOption('validation_groups')` and maybe somehow then execute it by myself. But I only want to get a simple array like `['person']` as `handleRequest` has already determined which groups should be used.

How to get that information from `FormInterface` or how to execute closure returned from config?

Comment: I may be missing something. Once you get the `$groups` function, isn't just `$groups($form)` what you want? The return of the function? (Or `call_user_func($groups, $form)` if you prefer)

Comment: You are right. I didn't think of calling this function in this way. It works fine. Thank you.